# Does Angular routing prevent server round-trips?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, routes

I'm picking up Angular, but when I got to the sections on Routing, I ran into a conceptual question.  The router is capable of taking a URL and rendering specific client-side DOMs based on the route.

The part I don't understand is whether or not the Angular router is hijacking the HTTP request.  If I am at URL http://localhost:4200/home , and I click on the address bar and type in http://localhost:4200/items , does the browser still send an HTTP request to the server, receive the entire page as a response, and then render the DOM on the client side?  Or does the Angular router somehow intercept the navigation request, cancel it, and handle the rendering entirely on the client?

I've seen blogs and such that suggest that the latter is the case.  I don't understand how that could be, as it seems to me that if client-side javascript was capable of intercepting navigation attempts from the browser, it would be trivial for malicious pages to hijack the user's browser and prevent them from leaving entirely.

Local testing with Fiddler seems to suggest that a round-trip is in fact made, but given my relative inexperience with the framework and the variety of "how-to" tutorials that seem to suggest the opposite, I'm unsure.  Can anyone clear up for me how exactly the router works, client-side/server-side?

Comment: The router can't intercept typed-in URLs so the browser will do the HTTP request. Typically the server would then route to the application and then the router would take over again, loading the appropriate component.